# How can I center my maps on the container and adjust the size so that it occupies the entire container?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am drawing a map of the United States,Costa Rica and Canada. And I would like the maps to adapt to the size of the `div#statesvg`

`<div id="statesvg" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>`

the size of `div#statesvg` is dynamic.

I only want by default that the maps fits exactly to the div that contains it.

I'm trying to center each map, but it's not centered. I would like to know if there is any mathematical formula or something to scale the map until it fully occupies the svg container.

```
  if(json=="usa.json"){
  // D3 Projection
    var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
                   .translate([width/2, height/2])
                   .scale((height*1.25));
  }

  if(json=="canada.json"){
  //canada lat long 54.6965251,-113.7266353 
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
             .center([-113.7266353,54.6965251   ])
                   .translate([width/2, height/2])
                   .scale((height*1.25));
  }

  if(json=="costarica.json"){
  //costa rica lat long
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
             .center([-87.0531006,8.351569  ])
                   .translate([width/2, height/2])
                   .scale((height*1.25));
  }          
  // Define path generator
  var path = d3.geo.path()               // path generator that will convert GeoJSON to SVG paths
             .projection(projection);  // tell path generator to use albersUsa projection
```

[image]

this is my actual problem for each map

[image]

thanks!

this is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lJgx0fbLcEh7e4W3j6XD?p=preview

Comment: I  don't think it's a duplicate (at least not of the proposed duplicate).

Comment: @yavg, you are right not a duplicate of the one I linkd..  I've re-opened it.  This question has been asked many times though.

Comment: @Mark Thanks, but in this case, it is a question that many users can help. At least in my case I have seen examples of how to center the map (I do not know what I am doing wrong), but I do not know how to scale it to fit the container. It is a question that solves two problems in one. I would really appreciate it if you can help me please.

Comment: @XavierGuihot thank you very much friend. Thank you for first reading and not judging. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this [nice gist](https://gist.github.com/nrabinowitz/1756257) from nrabinowitz, which provides a function which scales and translate a projection to fit a given box.

It goes through each of the geodata points (`data` parameter), projects it (`projection` parameter), and incrementally update the necessary scale and translation to fit all points in the container (`box` parameter) while maximizing the scale:

```
function fitProjection(projection, data, box, center) {
  ...
  return projection.scale(scale).translate([transX, transY])
}
```

I've adapted part of your code (the Canada map) to use it:

```
d3.json("canada.json", function(data) {

  var projection =
    fitProjection(d3.geo.mercator(), data, [[0, 0],  [width, height]], true)

  var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

  d3.select("#statesvg svg").remove();

  var svg = d3.select("#statesvg").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width+"px")
    .attr("height", height+"px");

  svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(data.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("stroke", "#fff")
    .style("stroke-width", "1")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return "rgb(213,222,217)"; });
});
```

As commented by the author, it seems to only work for Mercator projections.